# NLog UWP delete/export logs manually

Tags: c#, uwp, nlog

I'm using NLog in a C# UWP app.
I would like to add a button for deleting/exporting all logs created by NLog manually.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Exporting logs should create a ZIP file which I then can save to a given path.

Comment: How have you configured Nlog? Where are the logs written?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/UWPX/UWPX-Client/blob/master/Logging/NLog.config) is my NLog config file and [here](https://github.com/UWPX/UWPX-Client/blob/67b1af04550ecb9ebbb002bb2ff1813b9462480d/Logging/Logger.cs#L28-L32) you can find the logger creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your NLog configuration shows that it saves the logs in the application folder's `Logs` subfolder:

```
Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Logs")
```

You can find this folder manually by going to `C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Packages`, searching for your app's package ID and going to `LocalState`, where should be `Logs` as a subfolder.

### Deleting logs

Deleting logs is quite easy - you go into the logs folder and try to delete all files inside:

```
var logsFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync(
                         "Logs", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
var items = (await logsFolder.GetItemsAsync()).ToArray();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    try
    {
        await item.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete);
    }
    catch
    {
        //ignore exception - could happen if some file is currently open
    }
}
```

Because some files could be currently open by the logger, I am intentionally skipping potential exceptions.

### Exporting logs

Exporting requires you to first create a `zip` file from the logs folder. You can use the `ZipFile` API to do this. After you have the file, you can, for example, share it using the system share UI.

```
private async void Export()
{
    var logsFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync(
        "Logs", 
        CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

    //first delete existing export if there is one
    var zipFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
                           .TryGetItemAsync("LogsExport.zip");
    if (zipFile != null)
    {
       await zipFile.DeleteAsync();
    }

    //create zip export of logs
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(logsFolder.Path, 
                                Path.Combine(
                                     ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path,
                                     "LogsExport.zip"),
                                CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);

    //do something with the exported file 
    var dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
    dataTransferManager.DataRequested += DataTransferManager_DataRequested;
    DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
}

private async void DataTransferManager_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender,
                                                     DataRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    var dataRequest = args.Request;

    //mark operation as asynchronous
    var deferral = dataRequest.GetDeferral();

    //setting title is mandatory
    dataRequest.Data.Properties.Title = "Share exported logs";

    //set shared file
    var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(
        Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path,
        "LogsExport.zip"));            
    dataRequest.Data.SetStorageItems(new IStorageItem[]{ file });

    //unsubscribe event
    var dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
    dataTransferManager.DataRequested -= DataTransferManager_DataRequested;

    //complete operation
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

Because we need to get access to the `StorageFile`, we need to make the operation asynchronously, so we use `dataRequest.GetDeferral()` to tell the system that we started an asynchronous operation and it should wait for `dataRequest.Complete()` when the data will be ready.